# Android : Spinner : set ArrayAdapter in code want no call onItemSelected and only call when user click on spinner

Tags: android, kotlin, android-spinner

Android Spinner : When i set ArrayAdapter in code, android call onItemSelected. it's possible only call when user click on spinner items ?

listener

```
binding.spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
        override fun onItemSelected(adapterView: AdapterView<*>?, view: View, i: Int, l: Long) {
            value = binding.spinner.selectedItem.toString()

            when (value) {
                'a' -> {
                    valueId = 1
                    Log.d("onItemSelected", "valueId = 1")
                }
                'b' -> {
                    valueId = 2
                    Log.d("onItemSelected", "valueId = 2")
                    
                }
                else -> {
                    valueId = 0
                    Log.d("onItemSelected", "valueId = 0")
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onNothingSelected(adapterView: AdapterView<*>?) { return }
    }
```

spinner setting adapteur

```
val values = arrayOf('Choice : ', 'a', 'b', 'c')  
val adapterSpinner = ArrayAdapter(mContext, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, values)
            binding.spinner.adapter = adapterSpinner
```

May be it s possible to change values on spinner with other solution ?

Comment: hello, I cannot still understand what what do you want to achieve and what is your problem. Can explain a bit more about the flow of your problem and your desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution. It s possible with alternative of Android Spinner with `ListPopupWindow`. I can change adapter without call event `onItemSelected`.